# Pass multiple types of data arrays through method c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, parameters, arguments

I'm creating a method that loops through each element of an array, how can i pass **any** type of data array to be used in the method?

This is what i have at the moment

```
public void loopThrough(ARRAY TO BE PASSED THROUGH)
        {
            for(int x = 0;arr.length;x++)
        }
```

As in if i have an int array, a char array etc. How can i pass them through without having a separate method for each data type? I.E loopThroughInt, loopThroughChar

Comment: Have a look at the [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228502.aspx)

Comment: Depends upon what you need to do inside the method. Can you give some hint about what that method is supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks, it appears that's the main answer here XD. I'll choose Tim's answer when the timers up.

Comment: I'm looping through the array to find strings that have vowels and removing them, however i'd like to keep this method handy to save me continually using for loops to loop through arrays of all types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use generics:

```
public void loopThrough<T>(T[] arr)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
    {
        T t = arr[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use generic as your parameter data type

```
public void loopThrough<T>(T[] arr)
{
    for(int x = 0;x < arr.Length;x++)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics, although the next question will be what to do with the generic value.

```
public void loopThrough<T>(T[] arr) {
    for(int x = 0; arr.length; x++) {
        T v = arr[x];
    }
}
```